# How do I make this flask app suitable for Google Cloud Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am currently trying to use google cloud engine to deploy my flask web app and I am not sure how I need to modify the folder structure and some of the file names to match the requirements.

I have a flask app structured like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── styles.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       ├── archive.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── bootstrap.html
│       ├── editor.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── _post.html
│       ├── post.html
│       └── tag.html
├── app.db
├── app.yaml
├── blog.py
├── config.py
└── requirements.txt
```

GCE's requirements look like the file structure on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service) and include a `main.py` file at the top level.

I have `blog.py` at the top level which defines the application instance. Does this need to be the `main.py` file?

And would I need to modify the `app.yaml` file to represent this different file structure?

**EDIT:** I renamed `blog.py` to `main.py` and added the following lines to `app/__init__.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

But running `python main.py` does not make the app available on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service) should help you with the next steps, which you may or may not have already:

1. Creating a `templates/` folder.
2. Creating a `static/` folder.
3. Writing the code in your `main.py` file.
4. Specifying dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file.
5. Definining your web service settings in the `app.yaml` file. *You will need to modify the handler url to to point to the proper directories based on your project file structure*. See the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) for details.

To answer your question, this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to `app.yaml`.

As the  the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup)points out, *"App Engine will also automatically add the gunicorn to your `requirements.txt` file if you don't specify the entrypoint field."*

Finally, you will [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/deploying-web-service) your application to Google App Engine. You will issue the following command from the root directory of your project, where your `app.yaml` file is located:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I found a nice image (credits to this [article](https://medium.com/@dmahugh_70618/deploying-a-flask-app-to-google-app-engine-faa883b5ffab)) that depicts an overview of the process:

[image]